# How do I best manage commonly used Java libraries with Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

I have some java libraries I pretty much use in every project I create, and would very much like them to be added automatically or having them in some kind of global library. Is this possible using Eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

There's a section in the preferences called User Libraries that let's you create a collection of JAR files that can easily be added to any project's Build Path > Libraries section. If the Java libraries that you are trying to include are public, setting up Maven or Ivy to manage your dependencies is probably the better solution in the long term.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider a build tool like maven, which integrates beautifully with eclipse, and does all your dependency management for you.  That way, you're just copying bits of xml around and when one of your projects suddenly needs a different version, it doesn't break all the other projects.

http://maven.apache.org/eclipse-plugin.html